# Show that if $f$ and $g$ have the same Fourier series, and f, g are both continuous, then f = g on $[-\pi, \pi]$. (f, g has periodic $2\pi$)

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

By using a suitable convergence theorem, show that if $f$ and $g$ have the same Fourier series, and f, g are both continuous, then f = g on $[-\pi, \pi]$. (f, g has periodic $2\pi$)

If the partial sum of the Fourier Series, say, $S_n(f;x)$, which is (by assumption) equal to $S_n(g;x)$, converges uniformly to function $f$ and $g$, then the problem would be easily solved:

given $\epsilon\gt0, \exists N_1,N_2\in \mathbb{N}$, such that when$n\gt N_1, N_2$, respectively we have

$|f-S_n(f;x)|  \le {\epsilon\over2} 
, |g - S_n(f;x)| \le {\epsilon\over2} $

then, $|f - g| \le |f-S_n(f;x)| + |g - S_n(f;x)| \le {\epsilon\over2} + {\epsilon\over2} = \epsilon$ for $\forall n\gt max\{N_1, N_2\}$

However, I am aware that the above argument is based on the belief that the partial sum will uniformly converge. To prove the uniformity, I find this theorem:

Theorem: The Fourier series of a 2π-periodic continuous and piecewise smooth function converges uniformly.

But apparently, we lack the information to verify whether the conditions will meet. So what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use uniform convergence. But $S_n(f)$ converges to $f$ as well as $g$ in $L^{2}([-\pi,\pi])$ and this implies $f=g$ almost everywhere. By continuity $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: thank you so much! how can I state this idea in mathematical language? since $lim \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f - S_n|^2 dx = lim \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |g - S_n|^2 dx = 0$ doesn't give relationship between f and g explicitly.

Comment: @ZKK In  a metric space a sequence cannot converge to two different limits.

Comment: Let $f_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n (A_j\cos jx +B_j\sin jx)$be the $n$th partial sum of the Fourier series for $f(x)$. Theorem (Fejer):  If $f$ is continuous with period $2\pi$ then $\frac {1}{m+1}\sum_{n=0}^mf_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$ as $ m\to\infty.$

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ and $g$ have the same Fourier series then
$$\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}p(t)(f(t)-g(t))\,dt=0$$
for any trigonometric polynomial $p$, for $c_n(f)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^\pi e^{-inx}f(x)\,dx =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^\pi e^{-inx}g(x)\,dx =c_n(g)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$).
By Stone-Weierstrass theorem (complex version)
$$\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\varphi(t)(f(t)-g(t))\,dt=0$$
for any continuous function $\phi$. In particular, when $f$ and $g$ are continuous, for $\phi(t)=\overline{f(t)-g(t)}$
$$\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}|f(t)-g(t)|^2\,dt=0$$ Hence $f(t)=g(t)$ almost surely and so, $f\equiv g$ (by continuity).

Comment: Hi Oliver, sorry to write it in here but could you undo-delete your comment on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4156258/let-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-be-measurable-and-let-z-x-fx-0 so that reading the new proof of Ramiro would be easier for me? Thanks!