# Prove that $H=\{1/x|x \in E\}$ has measure zero if $E \subset (0,1)$ does.

Tags: analysis

I guess it's true for functions that are Lipshitz or uniformly continuous since we can limit the length of the intervals after the transformation.
However, I don't know if it's true or not, and since $1/x$ is not one of those, I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Write $H$ as $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty H_i$, where $H_i = \{1/x\mid x \in E \cap [1/i, 1]\}$ and then show that each $H_i$ has measure $0$.

Comment: Does $H_i$ have measure zero because of the uniform continuity of $1/x$ on $[1/I,1]$?

Comment: Uniformly continuous function can map a measure zero set to a set whose measure is not zero.

Comment: @Mod.esty does this mean that this method does not work? I’m kinda confused here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an interesting result that helps with your problem:

> **Theorem:** If $f:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is measurable, and $f$ is differentiable on a measurable set $C\subset(a,b)$, then
> $$m^*(f(C))\leq \int_C |f'(x)|\,dx$$
> where $m$ is Lebesgue's measure and $m^*$ is the outer measure.

See **Bruckner, A. M**. et. al., *Real Analysis*, 2nd ed 2008, section 7.3. for example, or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4158230/121671)

---

For your OP, consider $f:(0,1)\rightarrow(1,\infty)$ given by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Notice that $H=f(E)$. Applying the result stated above gives you
$$
m^*(H)=m^*(f(E))\leq\int_E\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx=0
$$
since $m(E)=0$.

---

**Edit:** It is also possible to show *directly* without using big machinery that $m(H)=0$ using only the concept of measure $0$ and the fact that the countable union of sets of measure zero has also measure $0$ (Most Advanced Calculus or basic Analysis books discuss this, for example **Apostol, T**. *Mathematical Analysis*, 2nd ed. Section 7.26)).

I leave many details to the OP. Start by splitting $(0,1]$ in a countable subintervals, for example $\{(\tfrac{1}{n+1},\frac1n]:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. The taks is then to show that each $H_n=\{\tfrac1x:x\in E\cap(\tfrac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]\}$ has measure zero. Notice that on each the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is Lipschitz on $I_n:=[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$, There exists a constant $L_n$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L_n|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in I_n$. Since $E\cap I_n$ has measure zero, then you can find a countable collection of intervals $J_{n,k}\cap _n=[a_{n,k},b_{n,k}$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\sum_k\ell(b_{n,k}-a_{n,k})<\frac{\varepsilon}{L_n}$$
where $\ell$ stands for length. Then
$$\sum_k|f(b_{n,k})-f(a_{n,k})|\leq L_n\sum_k(b_{n,k}-a_{n,k})<\varepsilon$$
Notice that $f(J_{n,k}\cap I_n)$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$ is a collection of intervals that cover $H_n$. That shows that $H_n$ has measure zero.

Comment: I’m sorry, but I’m not familiar with the concept of Lebesque measure and outer measure. Is there a way to solve this without using these concepts?

Comment: I think you should add in your OP what level you are at so the other can offer help accordingly. In any case, one can prove he statement just by knowing the notion of what a set of measure zero is, the however requires some work. You can divide the interval $(0,1]$ in subintervals, say $\{\big(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\big]: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and then show that each $H_n=\{1/x:x\in E\cap(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]\}$ has measusre $0$. I added some details to may answer, although I leave many details to you.

Comment: I see now. Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1):

For the record, here is the proof I had in mind when I wrote my comment. This is intended to address directly the problem implicit in the question, namely that taking reciprocals blows up the length of intervals near $0$. It uses two facts: (1) a set $E \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ has measure $0$ iff for any $\delta > 0$, there is a family of intervals $(x_n, y_n)$ , that cover $E$ (i.e., $E \subseteq \bigcup_i (x_i, y_i)$) and have total length less than $\delta$ (i.e., $\sum_i (y_i - x_i) < \delta$); (2) the union of a countable family of sets of measure $0$ has measure $0$.

Assume (1) holds for $E \subseteq (0, 1)$ and let $H_n = \{1/x \mid x \in E \cap [1/n, 1]\}$ for $n = 1, 2, \ldots$ Given $n$ and $\delta>0$, by our assumption, we can cover $E$ and hence $E \cap [1/n, 1]$ by intervals $(x_i, y_i)$ such that $\sum_i (y_i - x_i) < \delta/n^2$. But then $H_n$ is covered by the intervals $(1/y_i, 1/x_i)$ and we have:
$$
\sum_i\left(\frac{1}{x_i}- \frac{1}{y_i}\right) = \sum_i\left(\frac{y_i - x_i}{x_iy_i}\right) < n^2 \sum_i(y_i - x_i) < \delta
$$
because for $x_i, y_i \ge 1/n$, $1/(x_iy_i) < n^2$.
So, by (1), each $H_n$ has measure $0$ and $H = \{1/x \mid x \in E\} = \bigcup_n H_n$ is a countable union of sets of measure $0$ and hence by (2) has measure $0$.